# For a linear prediction model, does selective sampling to encompass the range of independent variable minimize number of samples required?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, linear-model

Suppose we have high confidence that $y=mx+c$ is a good model for a physical process based on previous experiments, and $m$ and $c$ vary with local/temporal conditions. We wish to predict $y$ for new populations, and want to find the minimum number of samples to determine $m$ and $c$, with goal of minimizing prediction error.

We could randomly sample $x$ and $y$, so traditional sample size rules of thumbs can be used (for example, 10 samples for a single independent variable). However, what if we could selectively sample $y$ and $x$ based on the variability of $x$, for example selectively sample so that the samples encompass a large degree of the variability of $x$ (and therefore $y$ given we know $y$ is linearly related to $x$). Does this reduce the number of samples required to achieve a certain prediction accuracy?

Comment: You ask about a "D-optimal design." In this exemplary case, the solution is easy to obtain algebraically and conforms with your intuition: set half the $x$ values to the smallest possible number and the other half of the $x$ values to the largest possible number.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, I wasn't aware of the optimal design methodologies. Similarly, I found informatino on Latin Hypercube sampling, which samples equal bins in the CDF of each feature to cover the parameter space. I think my example is conceptually similar to 1D LHS. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009830040500292X